# Difference between ghosts, specters, phantoms, wraiths, apparitions, phatasms, wights, and eidolons?

Tags: fantasy-races

See title. Are there agreed upon distinctions between these? I am making a world and I want to clearly define the different races/species/denizens of this world. It is a fantasy setting with magic. Any insight would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We help you solve problems about your world, and the differences you want to have between fictional species are entirely up to you, since they are fictional.

Comment: I have noted that phatasms tend to be phat.

Comment: Hello Konzon. I apologize, but I had to vote to close this. Asking us to define what is fundamentally a list of synonyms, even using the culturally-based myths and children's stories that are out there, is simply not what we do. @AlexP gave you a good general answer, but even it's subject to every culture's specific bedtime stories. To be honest, it's your story, and people want to become immersed in ***your*** world, not the world they already know. Create a world where all those things are distinctly different and you'll have fans thrilled to read your stories.

Comment: You might get some traction with the Mythology Stack exchange, but do your research first.

Comment: You forgot poltergeists, revenants, and banshees.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about mythology

Comment: In order to make this kind of question on topic for WB.SE, you might want to consider asking from the perspective of the world you are working on. For example: *I have ghosts which are like **this** and wights which are like **that** and eidolons which are like **the other** -- does this arrangement make sense in a world like the one I'm working on?* You'd have to support your proposed scheme with some salient facts about how your world works so we can determine if what you're asking makes any sense or passes a reality check.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer?

No.

These terms may (depending on setting) mean the same thing, utterly different things or multiple things per word. You just need to make sure that you as a world builder have the differences (if there are any) clear in your head, and then distinguish between people in-world who know the ‘right’ definition and people who don’t.

For example: your average Joe won’t distinguish between spectre or phantom. They’ll just scream ‘Ghost’. Your professional monster hunting badass, on the other hand, will know the specific differences that you as a world builder get to decide.

The only real help I can give is that wights and eidolons tend to be given physical bodies more often than not, while it’s the other way round for the other words.

Answer (score 7):

The words have different usages, and, although in some contrived contexts they *might* be made to be interchangeable, in most practical situations they are not.

- *[Eidolon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eidolon)* is the most general of the words on the list, in that it can refer to any real or virtual image representing any kind of imagined entity. Unfortunately is is very rarely used, and many people may have never encountered it. I would advise against using this word, especially because even those rare people who would recognize it as the unadapted form of the Greek word *eidôlon* may be astonished to learn that it doesn't mean *idol*. (I was.)
- *[Apparition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apparition)* means primarily an act of becoming visible or available. For example, we speak of the first apparition of a publication. It *might* mean an appearance of an unnatural entity, but this meaning is secondary and needs to be clarified in context. Even then, it usually refers not to the unnatural entity itself, but rather to its image becoming visible. For example, we may speak of the apparition of a ghost.
- *[Ghost](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ghost)* and *[phantom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/)* have a wide area of overlap, but there are many usages where the two words are not interchangeable. In medicine, you cannot say ghost limb instead of phantom limb; in computing, you cannot say ghost read instead of phantom read; in electrotechnics you cannot say ghost power instead of phantom power, although you can say ghost load instead of phantom load. When a person dies, we say that they gave up the ghost, and not the phantom. The Holy Spirit is the Holy Ghost, not the **Holy Phantom. (*Ghost* is the native Germanic word -- *Geist* in German. *Phantom* is the French oppressor's word, from Latin *phantasma*, itself from Greek; related to *fantasy*.)
- *[Specter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/specter)* is synonymous with *apparition* in the sense of an unnatural entity becoming visbile or manifest. By extenstion, it may be taken as a rarer synonym of *phantom*. (Here we have the same situation as with *ghost* and *phantom*, only this time in Latin; *spectrum* is the native Latin word, a derivative of *specio*, I look at, while *phantasma* is the fancy imported Greek word.) *Specter* is related to *specular*, *speculum*, *spectrum*, *species* and *special*. (The Latin verb *specio* has begotten very many descendants.) (Note that the distinction between the words *specter* and *spectrum* is peculiarly English. No other language has two forms of the Latin word *spectrum*.)
- I have no idea what *[wraiths](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wraith)* or *[wights](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wight)* are in the context of the given list. (But as you can see I can look them up in a dictionary.) They are very rare words. Note that many people may confuse *wraith* and *wreath*; and many people have only encountered the word *wight* as the name of the relatively well-known *[Isle of Wight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_Wight)*.

Comment: Wraiths and wights (as seen by your links) are both words of Norse / Germanic origin for spirits. Wight comes from Vaettir and is kind of a general elemental / nature spirit type creature (though in fantasy more associated with Tolkien's Barrow Wights I think) whereas wraith possibly comes from a word meaning a more human related traditional ghost. I wouldn't say either are rare though, certainly not among fantasy readers or RPG players.

Comment: Not at all rare to fantasy readers. But @adaliabooks reference to Tolkien exposes the problem with trying to definitively identify all these creatures. [Barrow-wights are wraith-like creatures in J. R. R. Tolkien's world of Middle-earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrow-wight). Tolkien borrowed the Norse mythology to create, not a creature, but a concept that has tickled the fancy of readers and gamers ever since. In that way, the use of the idea when writing is more important than the distinction - becuase in the end, it's just another noun.

Comment: Upvote for the OED quality linguistic side trips!

Comment: @JBH most of what we think of as fantasy staples are based on very loose and barely defined mythological start points, at the end of the day both elves and dwarves in Norse mythology were considered some form of spirits / vaettir but most wouldn't think to class them alongside ghosts now. As long as you stick to a specific regime (if you define Wraiths and Wights as different things early on don't use the terms interchangeably later) and you use them well that's the main thing.

Comment: @JBH also, humourously, Tolkien's Wights are actually more akin to Norse creatures like Draugr rather than the Vaettir whose name he used.

Comment: @adaliabooks I don't at all doubt it. It's why I made my comment to the OP - that he/she should create their own definitions. That's fundamentally what Tolkien did. He only used human myths as starting points to create a world that utilized words for convenience. Tolkien had a penchant for using the more arcane words in his day. "Wight" may be common today, but it probably wasn't before his day (which is why Alex can make his observation). Now that I think about it, I'm surprised the OP didn't include "lich" in the list.

Comment: @Willk: Those side trips are how I remember words. I insert them in answers and comments in the hope that other people will also find them mnemonically helpful.